# I am confused about finite and and non-finite verbs

Tags: finite-verbs

I was practising grammar and I had a problem in understanding finite and non-finite verbs. Basically, we can say that if a verb indicates past or present tense, it indicates number and person, we can say that it is finite but how about the verbs in the sentence "The goods have been stolen." 
Why is the modal have is a finite and been and stolen are non-finite.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Except for _be_, which is always an auxiliary, and _have_, which is usually an auxiliary, only third-person singular verbs in the present tense indicate number and person, and no other verb in English but _be_ indicates number and person of subject in the past tense. Any verb that is inflected for present or past tense is finite; all other verbs are non-finite. For all verbs, the present tense and the infinitive are the same form, and for regular verbs, the past tense and the past participle are the same form. In the sentence, _have_ is finite, _been_ and _stolen_ are non-finite.

Comment: As for modals, they don't inflect either, but since they have no non-finite forms (*_I have musted do that_, *_He wants to can do that_, *_Are you done musting do that?_), the only forms that they do have are considered finite.